# Nextjs - Cannot get url prarams(query) on server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So im trying to get req query aka GET params from the url into server side rendering for basicly validation and / login for authendication for example shopify shop but i cant really verify it or parse the shop before its parsed to the renderes page aka a component

I have tried both geninitialprops and getserverside props but its not returning the values in the url like /app?mydata=thisisworking&hmac=21SA92

**My code**

```
// _app.js
export default function InvenGroupApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  const isApp = pathname.startsWith('/app');
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>InvenGroup</title>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      </Head>

      <PolarisProvider theme={theme}>

        {isApp 
          ? <AppHandler Component={Component} {...pageProps} />
          : <Component {...pageProps} />
        }
        
      </PolarisProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

The direct component that should handle it

```
// @components/AppHandler.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppLayout from "@components/AppLayout";
import shopSession from '@lib/shop';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: { context }
  }
}

export default class AppHandler extends Component {

  render () {
    const { shop } = shopSession();
    const AppPage = this.props.Component;
    
    console.log(this.props);

    if (shop) {
      return (
        <AppLayout Component={AppPage}/>
      )
    }

    return (
      <AppPage>
        <div>Loading</div>
      </AppPage>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried in getInitialProps and getServerSideProps? Because that's where it should happen - you can get the request, and the query params, from the `context` in those functions.

Comment: @I'mJoeToo i have hereby updated it, i basicly looked at the nextjs documentation but well ye nothing

Answer (score 0):

To get the query parameters, you probably don't want to pass the full context object as props - way too much unclear and unnecessary data.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // The query params are set on `context.query`
  const { query } = context
  return {
    props: { query }
  }
}
```

In your example url of `/app?mydata=thisisworking&hmac=21SA92`, this would give your class component `this.props.mydata` and `this.props.hmac`.

Comment: when doing it and try logging in console it gives undefined, can it be that i need to pass it in _app or ?